# Javascript set values at input fields but on submit, the form says that "This field is required"

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, input

I have a login form where I am requested to get the username/password combinations from the URL and set them at the input fields of the login form in order to prepare them for the user. The following code enters the values at the input fields (showing the approach for the username, approach is same for the password), but on Submit button, I get the message that "This field is required", even though the input field has already a value set by me.

```
document.getElementById("username").value = chatUsername //e.g. afubauirafa
var loginButton = document.getElementsByClassName("rcx-button")[0];

loginButton.addEventListener("click", function() { 
    document.getElementById("username").setAttribute("aria-invalid", "false")
    document.getElementById("username").classList.add("focus-visible");
};
```

HTML input field:

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="example@example.com" aria-invalid="false" id="username" size="1">
<button type="submit" class="rcx-button">Login</button>
```

[image: On page load, input fields are populated]

[image: On pressing the Login button, it says that I have not entered data]

[image: Using Element Inspector on page load]

[image: Using Element Inspector after pressing the Login Button]

Comment: The code that form uses to determine if the fields have been filled, but which **you haven't shown us**, isn't compatible with the way you are filling the fields.

Comment: Aside from the issue, but never, ever send user credentials in the URL and absolutely don't send them in plain text

Comment: Excellent security. Passwords passing in the clear on every network hop between the client and the server, as well as being stored in the browser history.

Comment: The username and password are auto-generated for anonymity reasons. I understand your point, which is valid, yet this is the agreed approach with auto-generated username/passwords before hand, which are generated beforehand.

Comment: Maybe the validation itself is triggered by a click handler on the login button - in which case your code, which adds an additional click handler to set the values, might simply be too late. Have you tried populating the fields on page load, instead of waiting for the login button click?

Comment: Tried doing that using a "window.onload= setTimeout(waitLoad, 1000)" and wrapping all code inside the waitLoad() function, yet the behavior remains at it is

Comment: Auto generated username / password is not the issue people are trying to point out.  `<Form/>` default action is `GET`, you really need to change this to `POST`, and as long as your using `https`, your security is fixed.

Comment: Isn't this a response from server with validation errors?

Comment: Beyond the obvious security problems pointed out many times, your code does not show how you are capturing the parameters from the URL and assigning them to the fields. It is therefore impossible to answer to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, for user credentials you should always use the POST method as it hides it from the URL bar and general viewing. The two things to pay attention to are the method and action attributes in the HTML form element as well as the name attributes in the input elements that nested inside it (username, password, etc.). With the method, put it as POST and with the action, you will need to have a php script to handle the processing and obviously a second html page to display the results. As an example, the opening tag of your html form element should look something like "form id="form" method="POST" action="./example.php" required (with opening and closing syntax)" and further on from that, check out W3 schools for tutorials on php form handling. Hope that helps :)

Comment: This would have been a valid answer for a question on security, but this, however fails to answer the actual question.